# Mapping neighborhoods in Altair using TIGER GIS data

Tags: python, polygon, tiger

I'm trying to map the polygons and create a pop-up for the following incorporated areas in Florida:

```
Little Haiti
Allapattah
Wynwood
North Miami
Miami Gardens
```

My output should be a map in [Altair](https://altair-viz.github.io/) of the geographic bounds of those areas but I get a very distorted map when I run the following (I suspect is because I'm getting results from all areas represented by `025` but I'm not sure how to specify that.

Here's a link to census codes if it's helpful: https://www.census.gov/prod/techdoc/cbp/cbp95/st-cnty.pdf

```
tiger.available()
cxn = tiger.TigerConnection('tigerWMS_ACS2019')
cxn.layers

flaGeo = cxn.query(layer=20, where='COUNTY = 12')
flaGeo = flaGeo.to_crs({'init': 'epsg:4326'})

alt.Chart(flaGeo).mark_geoshape(stroke='white')
```

I've also tried:

```
flaGeo = cxn.query(layer=20, where='GEOID = 12025')

flaGeo = cxn.query(layer=20, where='STATE = 25' and 'COUNTY = 12')
```

Comment: Is this the Altair that you are using? => https://altair-viz.github.io/

Comment: Yes. I'm trying to pull down Tiger data feed into Altair.